# Why can I no longer answer without any obvious reason, and no recovery seems possible?

Tags: support, post-ban

When I try to post an answer, I get

> "We are no longer accepting answers from this account. See this meta
>   post to learn more."

On that page, it shows only that it seems a ban and is permanent, meaning I cannot help the community anymore.

I only posted twice, so how do I contact an admin?

Comment: So if you read the linked post in its entirety, you would have seen that the ban is automatic and no admin/moderator was involved.

Comment: Twice? Really? I can see four answers in your account and bet that you have more that got deleted after being downvoted. Please don't lie. As for the ban it's permanent until you either improve existing answers or post questions that will get enough upvotes.

Comment: *"it shows only that it seems a ban and is permanent"* ... read it again and in full.

Comment: I re-opened it because this user can't see his own answers; so there's no way for them to solve their problem. It is a duplicate, to be sure, but there's no way for them to get help without an actual answer to their question.

Comment: @LBT no worry we got more than enough users here to close it again. :)

Comment: @GeorgeStocker hmm.. maybe worth asking that moderators can post even in closed questions?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It'd be helpful, but it's less important to me than other feature requests (like post banned users being able to see all deleted questions/answers in their profile so they can actually improve their posts without posting on meta).

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: That sparks an idea...Meta Pong, the new game. We pick one, off-topic, question, close it, reopen it, close it again and so forth, and see how often we can do that, that's the score.

Comment: " the ban is automatic and no admin/moderator was involved" -> yes i read that, but that does not help. "four answers in your account" -> how do i access this info > couldn't find it in the account page. I didn't lie, i just don't remember two.

Comment: I've only posted 3 times. True story.

Comment: @KosPetoussis http://stackoverflow.com/users/1609960/kos-petoussis [screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lIpaP.png)

Comment: who is this user414076?

Comment: A user by the name of user414076?

Comment: @Kos he's using sarcasm, we have LOTS of people here saying those things e.g. "see, I have only this one post with no downvotes but still banned" and it turns out they have lots of other posts that were downvoted then deleted.

Comment: @Bart "read it again and in full" yes i did yesterday, but the question is what can anyone do about it to solve it? Obviously not by posting answers, so the only way would be to formulate a generally interesting Question. Which seems strange.

Comment: Read the answer by George with regards to improving your deleted answers. If you can make them actual good answers, they might be undeleted. Other than that, there is indeed the option to ask good questions or to gain reputation in other ways still possible to you. By suggesting edits for example. How much that would actually help I don't know given that the details of the banning algorithm are not public. If you don't do anything, then yes, the ban is permanent.

Answer (score 7):

Your answers have been deleted because of flags:

- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986296/what-are-the-differences-between-arraylist-and-vector/16747768#16747768), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439870/why-are-primes-important-in-cryptography/13383485#13383485), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050898/how-to-check-if-ping-responded-or-not-in-a-batch-file/16644583#16644583) should have been a comment.
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422673/evaluating-a-math-expression-given-in-string-form/16390547#16390547) used a language that was unhelpful and couldn't have been ported to the right language as written.

The system has now imposed a post ban on your account. The [only way to resolve it is to improve your answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) enough to be undeleted to have them upvoted by others.

If you can't post a comment, you shouldn't post a comment-as-an-answer instead. That will get your answers flagged and deleted.

Comment: AHA Now I see. I was new at using the site features. OK, now the next question is how do i change an answer to a comment.

Comment: @KosPetoussis You can't. Essentially the only way those answers can be improved is for you to turn them into actual answers.  Even if I convert them to comments, they still count for purposes of a post ban. I've linked you to your deleted answers, try to improve them to be actual answers.

Comment: Well the problem still is that for any question i only have an ANSWER button available, not a COMMENT. So I can never comment no matter how much i want it. Can you give me an enabled comment button?

Comment: @Kos Earn 50 reputation and you can comment anywhere.